# What is the EBNF grouping in yacc

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, ebnf

I am writing a program grammar with lex/yacc. I have an issue about ambiguity of grammar and i need to look EBNF grammar. When I searched semantic of yacc and its declarations, i see grouping(**{.....}**) but i do not know how i can initialize it. For example options(**[.....]**) initialize with **|**.

```
%token PROGRAM ID SEMICOLON
    program: 
             PROGRAM ID SEMICOLON
             | PROGRAM ‘,’ ID SEMICOLON
```

is there any way for grouping like that?

Comment: `{ … }` is a semantic action, not a grouping. Yacc does not do EBNF.

Comment: @rici i know but i want to know how i can initialize grouping in EBNF to yacc.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "initialize grouping". Yacc doesn't have grouping operators.

Comment: @rici i mean implementation, for example in real life you can draw a binary tree with nodes but its implementation in java or c is different.

Comment: When you say "grouping", do you mean repetition (which is written using curly braces in many EBNF syntaxes)? Because grouping (i.e. simple parentheses in most syntaxes) doesn't do anything without another operator involved. Like `A (B C) D` could just as well be written as `A B C D`. It's only something like `A (B | C) D` where the grouping makes a difference.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. The yacc rules you suggest will implement an optional comma, which seems to be what you want. Please say precisely what problem you had with that solution.

Comment: I understand with @sepp2k’s comment, there was a confusion in my head about EBNF and also thank you @rici

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yacc does not support EBNF, so you need to convert the EBNF operators to simple BNF to use in yacc.  In general, each such operator will require introducing a new symbol.  So

`[`...`]` becomes `<new-symbol>` with

```
<new-symbol> ::= ε | ...
```

`{`...`}` becomes `<new-symbol>` with<sup>1</sup>

```
<new-symbol> ::= ε | <new-symbol> ...
```

`(`...`)` becomes `<new-symbo>` with

```
<new-symbol> ::= ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>If there are any `|` operators in ..., you need to insert `<new-symbol>` after each one in this substitution</sub>